# SQL WHERE conditions

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a problem with SQL syntax.
**NON working code:**

```
$showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM adherence WHERE dateandtime='$chosendate' AND lastname='$lastname'");
```

**Working code 1:**

```
$showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM adherence WHERE dateandtime='$chosendate'");
```

**Working code 2:**

```
$showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM adherence WHERE lastname='$lastname'");
```

Separately - code works, but when using AND I get no results from database. Any idea?

**EDIT**

```
$showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM adherence WHERE dateandtime= :chosendate AND lastname= :lastname");
                $showdata->bindParam(':chosendate', $chosendate);
                $showdata->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
                $showdata->execute(); 
                $rowas = $showdata->fetch();
                foreach ($showdata as $rowas){
                echo '<div class="twenty name">', $rowas["lastname"], $rowas["firstname"], '</div>';
                }
```

EDIT 2 
**DATABASE:**
[image]

**ECHO'ing $chosendate and $lastname just above script. Result:**

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your table layout?

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) You should use [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements properly.

Comment: Are you sure there is a row where both of those conditions are true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've made a mistake in logic of your query, maybe there isn't any row which satisfies these two conditions. Apart from that you should use `Prepared Statement` properly:

```
$showdata = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM adherence WHERE
dateandtime= :chosendate AND lastname= :lastname");
$showdata->bindParam(':chosendate', $chosendate);
$showdata->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$showdata->execute();
```

Comment: $chosendate and $lastname are set correctly, Tried even echo them before this script.

Comment: Yeah you are right but i think there isn't any row which satisfies those two condition after WHERE.

Comment: Checked it 20 times, there is :) I can make an edit within few minutes

Comment: So would you please provide your table structure?

Comment: As I mentioned, separately $chosendate and $lastname giving data corretly

Comment: Found solution. I just needed to remove  $rowas = $showdata->fetch(); Thank you!